# Is there something bad about this puzzle?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, specific-question

I recently posted the puzzle [Evil Kidnappers are the worst!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18281/evil-kidnappers-are-the-worst), but it has received very little attention over the last 3 days. I'm not sure what's wrong with the puzzle (if any at all). Perhaps it's not interesting? My other 3 puzzles had received answers a lot faster, but the format isn't all that different.

Can anyone tell me how I can improve the quality of my puzzle, or tell me why it seems to be so unpopular?

---

Edit: It's now been 2 weeks. A bounty has gone and passed on the question, but it has received few views still. Seriously, anything I can do to improve it?

Comment: It would be legitimate to ask this as a comment to our own puzzle. Not everybody reads the "meta" sites.

Comment: I don't understand the recent edit. There are a few attempted answers, over a thousand views, and fifteen upvotes with zero downvotes. Obviously people don't *dislike* it. Perhaps it's just missing the hard/fun balance a bit?

Comment: I can attest to the fact that it's missing the hard/fun balance. It's an interesting puzzle that a lot of people want to *see* get solved, but whenever I look at it, there's a lot of numbers that blur together, a lot of riddle that blurs together, a bunch of hints that don't really make sense to me, and no real direction to go with it. And thus I have not attempted to solve it.

Comment: @BaileyM Even with the super direct hint at the very end of the post (most recent hint?) If it's missing a hard/fun balance, which part of it is it leaned too much towards? How can I make it so that it's more "balanced"?

Comment: @Geobits I'm more bothered by by the fact that the puzzle remains unsolved after 2 weeks, even though I intended this to be a fairly easy puzzle (I've tested it on other people before, they were able to solve it within 10 minutes, without the hints, but with a little of my verbal guidance which are now translated into hints). The view count also hasn't risen very much, so it's not really attracting anyone new to try, and the only ones it has attracted are the ones who "want to see it solved".

Comment: As helpful as you think the hint is, I still can't solve the riddle, so I'm pretty much stuck. You should tell those friends of yours to come join P.SE, as they sound quite intuitive!

Comment: @BaileyM can you tell me what part you're stuck on? If you posted maybe a partial answer I might be able to tell you where you went wrong. I suspect this is also part of the problem, where people don't post where they're at but give up instead - makes it hard for me to judge where people are stuck and to give appropriate hints.

Comment: Your puzzle doesn't get enough attention? Posting it on meta certainly will!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think anything is wrong with this puzzle. As of now, it has 7 up-votes and 5 fav-markers, so it's doing good. Just don't be impatient. Good puzzles may take a while to be tackled and not everybody posts during this "working" time.

I'm not sure if this is a valid assumption, but I sometimes wonder if "a lot of favorite-markers" mean something like:

> *"I'm very interested in this puzzle - or how it would solve - but I'm too busy/not good enough/whatever to solve it myself."*

If this is the case, then puzzles with a lot of fav-markers might be on the "too hard" side of things - but still not to worry.

If you get the impression that you want to "push" your puzzle, you can do so by adding a bounty. (Once your own rep is high enough.)

Also: Weekends tend to be a bit "slower" as well. I guess most people work on puzzles during their *working hours* ?!??

Comment: Well, we've got to send time with family during the weekends. It's not like our bosses would mind if we spend a little time for puzzles, right?

Comment: I use the iphone app most of the time.  It has a much easier way to get to the favorites list.  Any puzzle that I am interested in solving but can't at that time gets a favorite.